# Running a node.js script in Komodo console

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, komodo

I'm having trouble running a test script. I have the standard configuration:
[image]

and the file settings:

[image]

but when I run the script I get this:

[image]

Where is my "Hello World" string? If I add code that would normally produce an error, it will display the error fine. Is it debugging instead of running the script? I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Komodo does not support node.js 12... yet.

http://forum.komodoide.com/t/node-js-debugger-never-finishes-starting/1321

Since there is no stable release of node.js 11, I downloaded the lastest stable release of 10, and everything works fine.

http://blog.nodejs.org/2015/01/26/node-v0-10-36-stable/